# Flexbox streching children on safari

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a flex container with children inide (these are cards with images inside).

On Safari only, one of the card's images is being streched - please see below.

[image]

When I view this in chrome and firefox with the dev tools it looks perfectly fine.

[image]

Do you know what would be causing this issue for safari only? I'll paste the relevant code below.

```
              <div class="tool-title-container">
                <h3 class="tool-title">Front end</h3>
                <div class="tool-title-background"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="tool-logos">
              
                <div class="tools-card">
                    <div class="tool-imgs-container">
                        <img src="imgs/html-css-js-logo.png" alt="html-css-js-logo" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tools-card">
                    <div class="tool-imgs-container">
                        <img src="imgs/react-logo.png" alt="react-logo" />
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tools-card">
                    <div class="tool-imgs-container">
                        <img src="imgs/material-ui-logo.png" alt="material-ui-logo" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


.tool-title-container {
    position: relative;
}

.tool-title-background {
    position: absolute;
    max-width: 15rem;
    height: 50%;
    background: var(--primary-brand);
    opacity: 0.3;
    z-index: -1;
    top: 0.5rem;
    transform: var(--random-deg);
}

.tool-title {
    font-size: 2rem;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: var(--text-primary)
}

.tools-card {
    box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-lg);
    display: block;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
    border-radius: 32px;
    margin: 1rem auto;
    transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
    border: 1px solid var(--dark-border);
    margin: 1rem;
    background: var(--white);
}

.tools-card:hover {
    transform: translateY(-1rem);
    transition: 300ms;  
}

.tool-logos {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.tool-imgs-container {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
    padding: 0.5rem;
    background: var(--white);
}

.tool-imgs-container img {
    max-width: 12rem;
}
```

Comment: check my answer and if it resolves your problem , upvote and accept. cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
.tool-imgs-container {
   align-items: flex-start
}
```

Since the default for `align-items` is `stretch`.

```css
.tool-title-container {
  position: relative;
}

.tool-title-background {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 15rem;
  height: 50%;
  background: var(--primary-brand);
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0.5rem;
  transform: var(--random-deg);
}

.tool-title {
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-weight: 300;
  color: var(--text-primary)
}

.tools-card {
  box-shadow: var(--box-shadow-lg);
  display: block;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 0.5rem 0.5rem;
  border-radius: 32px;
  margin: 1rem auto;
  transition: transform 300ms ease-in-out;
  border: 1px solid var(--dark-border);
  margin: 1rem;
  background: var(--white);
}

.tools-card:hover {
  transform: translateY(-1rem);
  transition: 300ms;  
}

.tool-logos {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.tool-imgs-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-evenly;
  padding: 0.5rem;
  background: var(--white);
  align-items: flex-start;
}

.tool-imgs-container img {
  max-width: 12rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="tool-logos">          
  <div class="tools-card">
      <div class="tool-imgs-container">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RBiHov0.jpeg" alt="html-css-js-logo" />
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tools-card">
      <div class="tool-imgs-container">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RBiHov0.jpeg" alt="react-logo" />
      </div>
  </div>
  <div class="tools-card">
      <div class="tool-imgs-container">
          <img src="https://i.imgur.com/RBiHov0.jpeg" alt="material-ui-logo" />
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```